# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' 3.0

Tags: python

Getting a TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'error. any help appreciated.

```
userEuro = raw_input("What amount in Euro do you wish to convert?")

    USD = userEuro * 1.3667
```

Answer (score 1):

`raw_input()` return value which user enter in a `string`

So type of `userEuro` variable is string, you can check by `type()` method

```
>>> userEuro = raw_input("What amount in Euro do you wish to convert?")
What amount in Euro do you wish to convert?1.2
>>> type(userEuro)
<type 'str'>
>>> userEuro
'1.2'
```

---

Do **type casting** to convert from string to float.

```
>>> float(userEuro)
1.2
>>>
```

---

Do **exception handling** during type casting because user may enter wrong value as input.

```
>>> userEuro = raw_input("What amount in Euro do you wish to convert?")
What amount in Euro do you wish to convert?ab
>>> userEuro
'ab'
>>> float(userEuro)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ab

>>> try:
...    float(userEuro)
... except ValueError:
...    print "Wrong value for type casting: ", userEuro
... 
Wrong value for type casting:  ab
>>>
```

---

**What is `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'` exception:**

When we multiply string by float value then this exception is coming.

```
>>> "1.2" * 1.3667
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

**String is multiple** by integer value

```
>>> "test" * 2
'testtest'
```

But String **is not** multiple by integer or float value

```
>>> "test" * '2'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
>>>
```

---

**Python 3.x**

`raw_input()` method is remove from the Python 3.x,

`raw_input()` for Python 2.x

`input()` for Python 3.x

Answer (score 0):

`userEuro` is a string. You should convert it to a float by using `float(raw_input())`.

FYI, a string can be multiplied but only by an integer. This results in a string concatenation:

```
print 'a' * 2
>> 'aa
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the second line to :

```
USD = float(userEuro) * 1.3667
```

raw_input accepts the user input as a `String`.
You will need to convert it into float before performing the above mathematical operation on it.